# Procedural (AO/Cavity) dirt

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

[image]

I want to add dirt to this robot. I dont want to UV all the tiles of the robot, but I have heard some guys talking about adding procdural grunge and wear to cravicces and egdes

like for example between these pipes:

[image]

Here is the .blend file with just the robot:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=53085

Comment: Hello :). What exactly is your question? What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck?